# how to improve processing the rows and colums

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this structure that collected from a grib2 file.
xrecord.values[row,col] gives the value for X and
xrecord.level gives the level for the record
xrecords is list of xrecord objects for different levels.

I want to improve the performance of values_for_all_levels function which access these records by each row,col combination 
scan all the records and get the values.
values_for_all_levels function is the most time consuming function. I want to change the approach by,
combine level, X and Y values in a dictionary so that I can access [(level,X,Y),(level,X,Y),...] 
combination with row and col as the key. So I believe,
instead of using values_for_all_levels function all the time
 if I can map record values with rows and cols in an efficient way with only 1 heavy call, and then use myDict with key
I might gain performance. How can I achieve that mapping? Any help would be appreciated.

```
class myClass(object):
    levels = [x.level for x in self.xrecords]

    for xy_comb, data in self.iterator():
        do_something()

    def iterator(self, ixrows=None, ixcols=None):
        rows = ixrows or xrange(self.all_rows())
        cols = ixcols or xrange(self.all_cols())
        return (self.point_at_index(row, col) for row in rows for col in cols)

    def point_at_index(self, row, col):
        x_vals = self.values_for_all_levels(row, col, self.xrecords)
        y_vals = self.values_for_all_levels(row, col, self.yrecords)
        xx = self.xxlist[row, col]
        yy = self.yylist[row, col]
        return (xx, yy), zip(self.levels, x_vals, y_vals)

    def values_for_all_levels(self, i, j, records):
        return [r.values[i, j] for r in records]
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question, but is there a specific reason you cannot use `numpy` to save your records in a 3D matrix (i.e. dimensions x, y, level)? You can then access individual values, or a whole axis quite efficiently

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it doesn't fit with the structure I have. Because I have two type of records giving different values. And each xrecords represent another level. I should be able to access them with [row,col] and be able to get (x,y,level ) values for different levels which means [(x,y,level),...]